# String issue with Javascript adding dynamic HTML

Tags: php, javascript, escaping, innerhtml

I'm using PHP to generate a Javascript button that adds in a checkbox and some other HTML.

What is the proper way to escape these characters to include them in an onclick event?

I saw it suggested to convert ' and " to the ascii values, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

```
$tempOutput = "<a href='temp.txt'>\"Happy\"</a>";
$tempOutput = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $tempOutput);
$tempOutput = str_replace('"', "&quot;", $tempOutput);
```

just results in this if you echo the string right before use:

```
<a href=&#39;temp.txt&#39;>&quot;Happy&quot;</a>
```

and this if you inspect the page element:

```
<a onclick="
                    var divTag = document.createElement('div');
                    divTag.innerHTML = '&lt;a href='temp.txt'&gt;&quot;Happy&quot;&lt;/a&gt;';
                    document.getElementById('extraDiv').appendChild(divTag) ;
                ">test</a>
```

I've also tried just appending to the extradiv's innerHTML but no success there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mostly use PHPs rawurlencode() and Javascript's unescape():

```
  <?php
    $tempOutput = '<a href="temp.txt">'.htmlentities('"Happy"').'</a>';
  ?>
  <a onclick="
              var divTag = document.createElement('div');
              divTag.innerHTML = unescape('<?php echo rawurlencode($tempOutput);?>');
              document.getElementById('extraDiv').appendChild(divTag) ;
             ">test</a>
  <div id="extraDiv"></div>
```

This will also avoid errors with other chars, e.g. linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks.  This works except for the fact you have to do the htmlentities() first.  I essentially cannot do that since the HTML is returned from another source.  I don't generate it right before putting it in the onclick.  htmlentities() on the whole string doesn't exactly work.  Basically everything is okay as long as there's not a double quote in any text in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Escape like this

```
$tempOutput = str_replace(array("'",'"'), array("\'",'&quot;'), $tempOutput);
```

Comment: This worked for the very simple example, but it threw an error again with a more complex example, but it's a start thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: I think I want sort of the opposite, but thank you.  My input is already in this format.